# How to configure a security message generated by reverse proxy/Big IP

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, big-ip

I have a client with a Big IP reverse proxy that generates a pop-up message, which the user needs to accept for outbound requests.  I would like to setup a similar proxy for testing against on a dev server.

Is there a specific name for the feature that creates the pop-up message?  Are there any open source solutions with a similar feature?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a dev environment and BIG-IP is part of your solution stack, for $95 USD you can get a Developer license of BIG-IP. This will allow you to mirror production instances and configurations while keeping cost way down.  I used to use staging BIG-IP environments for my development work but as it's staging, I was stepping on too many toes with config changes.  The Dev license allows me to run a BIG-IP virtual in VMware Fusion and not bug anyone.  I then run a secondary Dev BIG-IP on ESX that my team can share... works great and allows us to properly evaluate our app's traffic across what it will run in production.

https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/f5-developer-edition-how-to-obtain-a-developer-license-key

Alternatively, can you put your dev instance behind the production BIG-IP and get a new virtual IP associated for you?  That way you could reuse the pop-up iRule (assuming it's an iRule).

Comment: Thank you for the information.  Unfortunately I don't have the option to develop in the production environment, but this definitely gives me something to get started.

Comment: Probably a good idea not to dev in prod unless you like playing with fire.  ;-)